# Why does null coalescing operator result in one path with code coverage?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

Just running through some code coverage for a project and came across soemthing which I find perhaps a little odd/confusing.

```php
private function getOrder(int $order_id) : Order
{
    return Order::where('id', $order_id)->first() ??
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The order id is not valid');
    }
}
```

This method returns one branch and one path when looking at my code coverage report.
Instinct tells me that this should be two branches and two paths.

I've written tests for methods that utilize this private method but none of them test for the raising of an exception. I would have expected coverage to flag this up.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what if you start the new line with `??` instead of putting `??`  at the end of the line?

Comment: @Zakalwe you can you replace `where('id'` with `findOrFail($order_id)`. check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions).

Comment: @IGP I actually just formatted this for the question and it is on the same line.

Comment: @francisco this would just defer a different exception to be caught elsewhere. The issue isn't really about the data but the fact that as far as I can my understanding goes, this should have two branches. If we swap this out we would end with two possible statements:

`null ?? throw...` and `$model ?? throw...`

Comment: As far as I know, `phpunit` gets its code coverage functionality from an extension (phpdbg, xdebug or pcov). I think you might need to [open an issue on the repo](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues) to get more guidance on the matter. If branches are generated correctly when using the ternary operator, perhaps it's a weird quirk that still needs to be addressed.